# Flutter fetch Location and Latitude and Longitude

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, fluttermap

Currently, I am able to fetch the complete location (PlaceName, Latitude, and Longitude) in only one variable but I want to fetch these three things in a separate variable.
So that I can print only latitude or longitude or placename if I want.

```
Future fetchLocation() async {
currentLocation = await getLocationCoordinates();
setState(() {
  location = currentLocation;
});
}

Future<Map> getLocationCoordinates() async {
loc.Location location = loc.Location();
 try {
await location.serviceEnabled().then((value) async {
  if (!value) {
    await location.requestService();
  }
});
final coordinates = await location.getLocation();
return await coordinatesToAddress(
  latitude: coordinates.latitude,
  longitude: coordinates.longitude,
   );
  } catch (e) {
  print(e);
  return null;
 }
 }

Future coordinatesToAddress({latitude, longitude}) async {
try {
Map<String, dynamic> obj = {};
final coordinates = Coordinates(latitude, longitude);
List<Address> result =
await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromCoordinates(coordinates);
String currentAddress =
    "${result.first.locality ?? ''} ${result.first.subLocality ?? ''} 
${result.first.subAdminArea ?? ''} ${result.first.countryName ?? ''}, 
${result.first.postalCode ?? ''}";

print(currentAddress);
obj['Location'] = currentAddress;
obj['latitude'] = latitude;
obj['longitude'] = longitude;

 return obj;
  } catch (_) {
 print(_);
 return null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By THis function You will get current Location without lat and long

```
Future<Map> getLocationCoordinates() async {
loc.Location location = loc.Location();
 try {
 await location.serviceEnabled().then((value) async {
if (!value) {
await location.requestService();
  }
 });
final coordinates = await location.getLocation();
return await coordinatesToAddress(
latitude: coordinates.latitude,
longitude: coordinates.longitude,
 );
} catch (e) {
print(e);
   return null;
 }
 }
Future coordinatesToAddress({latitude, longitude}) async {
try {
 Map<String, dynamic> obj = {};
 final coordinates = Coordinates(latitude, longitude);
 List<Address> result =
  await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromCoordinates(coordinates);
 String currentAddress =
"${result.first.locality ?? ''} ${result.first.subLocality ?? ''} 
 ${result.first.subAdminArea ?? ''} ${result.first.countryName ?? ''}, 
   ${result.first.postalCode ?? ''}";

 print(currentAddress);
  

     return currentLocation;
    } catch (_) {
     print(_);
    return null;
       }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

You used **geolocator: ^7.3.0** dependency [here](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator)  you can found latitude longitude also using this dependency

Comment: I am getting the latitude and Longitude but i want both of them in seperate variable
obj['Location'] = currentAddress;
obj['latitude'] = latitude;
obj['longitude'] = longitude;

 return obj;